# I am facing problem in running my first ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using mac

I tried to run my first ionic project , But I am facing erroe in running it in my mac

I am putting all the steps that I have followed into Terminal -

1. Started with - : $ ionic start MyIonicProject tutorial
2. $cd MyIonicProject
3. $ionic serve

**then I am getting error**

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/user/.ionic/helper.log'
> ionic-app-scripts serve --address 0.0.0.0 --port 8100 --livereload-port 35729 --dev-logger-port 53703 --nobrowser

[INFO] Looks like @ionic/app-scripts isn't installed in this project.

       This package is required for this command to work properly.

? Install @ionic/app-scripts? Yes
> npm i -D -E @ionic/app-scripts
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/user/Projects/MyIonicProject/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /Users/user/Projects/MyIonicProject/node_modules/@ionic
npm ERR! path /Users/user/Projects/MyIonicProject/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/user/Projects/MyIonicProject/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/Users/user/Projects/MyIonicProject/node_modules'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/Users/user/Projects/MyIonicProject/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/user/Projects/MyIonicProject/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2018-09-21T06_24_56_379Z-debug.log
users-MacBook-Pro-3:MyIonicProject user$
```

Comment: Try installing node dependencies using "npm install"

Comment: I already have node_module folder inside the app  , your this solution is not helping me out

Answer (score 0):

Try running command by appending `sudo` as follows:

```
sudo ionic serve
```

Or

run below command in the terminal window:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/
```

This will change the permissions of every thing inside the local folder and then try below command:

```
sudo ionic serve
```

Answer (score 0):

> Looks like @ionic/app-scripts isn't installed in this project.

So try first this :

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

Then:

```
npm install
```

and

```
ionic serve -l
```